# why setting the height of the body to 100% sets automatically the width to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I noticed that setting the html and body height to 100%, the body's width seems to be set automatically to 100% (even if it does not appear among the css rules), why?

```
<html>
  <head
    <title>full screen</title>
    <style>
    html, body{
       margin: 0;
       height: 100%;
       background-color: rgb(200,50,50);
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/wocini/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The body element is a block level element and defaults to 100% width of its parent.

Comment: What @j08691 said ... this is true of all block level elements (not just the body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting these elements' heights to any value (or even not setting it at all) doesn't change their width, which is 100% by default due to them being `block` elements.

You can verify this by inspecting any HTML page in your browser and looking for the property `display: block;`, defined by `user agent stylesheet` (your browser), in these elements.